# Field tv_sec doesn't exist in struct SystemTime

Tags: rust

I'm attempting to get the last time a file was modified but I am getting an error of field not found.

```rust
use std::{fs, io, time};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let metadata = fs::metadata("foo.txt")?;
    let _time: time::SystemTime = metadata.modified().unwrap();
    let last_modified = _time.tv_sec;

    println!("{:?}", last_modified);
    Ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0609]: no field `tv_sec` on type `std::time::SystemTime`
 --> src/main.rs:6:31
  |
6 |     let last_modified = _time.tv_sec;
  |                               ^^^^^^ unknown field
```

I have also tried using the result without unwrapping but then I get to the same point where I want to access the `tv_sec` field of the struct.

As a reference before unwrapping the result is `Ok(SystemTime { tv_sec: 000, tv_nsec: 000 })` and after unwrapping it is just `SystemTime { tv_sec: 000, tv_nsec: 000 })`.

I am very new to Rust but I have combed the docs and from the docs it seems I should be able to access the field of the `SystemTime` struct like that.

Comment: Please dont use `_time` because `_` as prefix indicates, that that variable is not used, but you actually use that variable, so instead name it `time`.

Comment: @hellow Believe it or not I originally had `time` but the compiler yelled at me to change it to `_time` and I couldn't find out a reason why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access `tv_sec` because that field is not public. This is called visibility and you can read about it in [chapter 7.2 of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/second-edition/ch07-02-controlling-visibility-with-pub.html).

You can only call public methods on `SystemTime` which can be found in the [API of `SystemTime`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html).

---

The reason for the "strange" error message i, that although the debug representation suggests that it is a "flat" struct (e.g. it has two fields `tv_sec` and `tv_nsec`), [it is actually a tuple struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/time.rs.html#119), which means you have to call `.0` to get the inner field which then will result in the error

```
error[E0616]: field `0` of struct `std::time::SystemTime` is private
  --> src/main.rs:10:22
   |
10 |     println!("{:?}", time.0);
   |                      ^^^^^^
```

This is done to abstract over different OS; Windows handles the time differently than Unix, for example.

---

If you want to get the "age" in seconds you can convert it to a [`Duration`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html) by using [`SystemTime::elapsed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html#method.elapsed) which will give you back `Duration` where you can get the seconds by using [`Duration::as_secs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html#method.as_secs).

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the result of **SystemTime::now()** as a string from which the two numbers (**tv_sec** and **tv_nsec**) can be easily extracted.

```
   use std::time::SystemTime;
    
fn main(){
    let now = SystemTime::now();
    let now_str = format!("{:?}",now); //SystemTime { tv_sec: 1657846097, tv_nsec: 129747070 }
    let now_str_digits_spaces: String = now_str.chars().filter(|c| c.is_digit(10) || *c == ',').collect(); //"1657846097,129747070"
    let now_splitted: Vec<&str> = now_str_digits_spaces.split(",").collect(); //["1657846097", "129747070"]
    let  tv_sec:usize =  now_splitted[0].parse().unwrap(); //1657846097
    let tv_nsec:usize = now_splitted[1].parse().unwrap(); //129747070
    println!("{:?}", tv_sec);
    println!("{:?}", tv_nsec);
}
```